# installing Qt for VS2010

Tags: c++, qt, installation

after finding that its too hard to write GUI applications with WIN32API today im going to learn Qt. so I installed qt as follows.

first I installed VS 2010 express. its OK.

then downloaded `Qt libraries 4.8.3 for Windows (VS 2010, 235 MB)` from http://qt-project.org/downloads and installed it as a normal software. (in C:\Qt\4.8.3) it automatically installed assistant, designer ... ect.

then downloaded `Qt Creator 2.6.0 for Windows (51 MB)` from http://qt-project.org/downloads and installed it also as a normal program.

now in qt creater when I try to creat a Qt project it says that no valide kits found.

here are some screenshots of the issue im facing.

[image]
[image]
[image]
what should I do now to start qt. please I need someones help to procced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need QtCreator AND visual studio.
QtCreator is Qt's own IDE and uses g++/mingw as the compiler (included in the download).

Qt includes QtDesigner - the graphical UI designer that you can use with visual studio or QtCreator.

If you want to use VS, install the [qt-vs-addin](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/what_is_the_qt_visual_studio_add-in) and download the VS builds of the Qt libs.
If you want to use QtCreator, download the mingw builds of Qt.

Or in both cases you can download the source and build it from scratch using wither QtCreator or VS.

edit: You can make QtCreator use the VS compiler backend - in which case you should download the VS build of Qt. Personally I have never done this - if you are using VS then you may as well use the VS ide.

edit2: The free express version of VS can't use plugins - so its a bit of pain to use with Qt. In this case you should probably use QtCreator.

Comment: also with QTcreator you can use the .pro files that can make your life a lot easier and they are a cross-platform solution.

Comment: @user1797612 the visual studio plugin can read/write .pro files. But the OP's problem is that he has VS format libs and is trying to use mingw with them

Comment: so do I need to install mingw compiler too. but why do qt obtains versions as qt(VC 2010), qt(mingw). like that

Comment: @LakshanPerera QTcreator comes with a builtin version of MinGW, you don't need anything other than QTcreator itself. under Windows there are 2 "version" ( mingw and VS ) available because mingw and Visual Studio uses 2 different set of ABI, in a nutshell this mean that Visual Studio can't compile with a mingw version of the QT lib and viceversa.

Comment: @MartinBeckett i never heard of this plugin, but as general rule, i try to use VS as less as possible, it's an environment that under certain circumstances it's also really obsolete and old.

Comment: @user1797612 I added some screenshots on what im facing. so its no harm that i have installed vc. so pointout me how can I start with mingw from here.

Comment: @user1797612 personally I think VS is the best dev environment on any platform. There are c++ compilers that are more standards compliant - we used to use Intel icc as the backend. Although Msft's c++  is now pretty good - in vs2010 and 2012 it has improved a lot. ps the Qt-plugin makes all the Qt moc steps completely transparent

Comment: @LakshanPerera looks like you have not installed the complete SDK, try to use the package manager in the Help menu and update/install the missing components.

Comment: @MartinBeckett I have tested it for some time, mingw does everything better than VS, VS just creates a mess of files and configurations for just a simple project with 1 source file, doesn't offer a good support for C and C++ and I really don't see why people use it, we are talking about an environment that doesn't even support C99 (!). It's just ugly, verbose and old; also it's the most resource-hungry IDE around, sometimes not even Eclipse it's that hard to handle, it's just computing power going wasted.

Comment: @user1797612 developer computer power is cheap compared to developer time - I donb;t save money by underspeccing dev machines. Yes the mess of files it creates is untidy but I don't need to care, "makefile" can hardly be described as the best design ever (except compared to autoconf!).  VS support for C is poor - their excuse is that it's a c++ compiler, in practice it's because nobody except Linux kernel devs and embedded care about pure 'c'.

Comment: @user1797612 I cant find enything called package manager. ok I will download the complete SDK. where can i download it. please can u give me the link. is the complete SDK free.

Comment: @user1797612 if qt creater include a package of mingw how can I use it. currently I can see only the vc compiler